# Android Studio with scrolled activity

Tags: java, android, android-studio, smartphone

Sorry I'm new to android studio and Stack Overflow.
How can I create a page where image buttons are scrolled?
My project is made with java.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".Visitare">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="409dp"
    android:layout_height="729dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="1dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="1dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" />


</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Please post what have you tried so far

Comment: When I add Image Button it's not added in the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ScrollView`, like this:

```
<ScrollView
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:id="@+id/activity_main"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="What is Lorem Ipsum?"
        android:textSize="34sp" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry...like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum."
        android:textSize="14sp"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Why do we use it?"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:textSize="34sp"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry...like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum."
        android:textSize="14sp"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Where can I get some?"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:textSize="34sp"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum     available ... or non-characteristic words etc."
        android:textSize="14sp"/>

  </LinearLayout>
  </ScrollView>
```

Comment: ok but when i add Image Button, it's not added in the code